# Read Username/Password from sms iOS

Tags: ios, quicktypebar

I'm facing the following issue. I'm getting a sms while user login, where the user's new username and password are mentioned (both are numbers). Now I need to read the sms content and suggest the username data in `UsernameTextField` on `QuickType bar`, and do the same for the password in `PasswordTextField`. How can I implement this?

I know how to read and suggest a one time code (for verification, e.g.), but in this case I get two different codes.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official way to do this. iOS allows you only to set that a field is a password or a OTP kind, but doesn't allow to read the SMS messages, it will be suggested to the user automatically.